# Texmaker, Tex Live, .cls file, CentOS 8

Tags: texlive, texmaker, installing, linux, centos

I have just made a fresh install of Texmaker and Tex Live at my CentOS 8 system. I am not able to execute: "PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + View PDF" from the Texmaker. Everytime I get error at the beginning of my .tex document:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `wlscirep.cls' not found.
```

The beginning of the main.tex document appears as follows:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\title{Title of the document}
...
```

The wlscirep.cls was stored in the same folder as the main.tex document as default. It is not working like that. Why? I have no idea I thought Tex is everytime looking into the document root folder.

After reading this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te?newreg=87276612476c478c802cbbd9d1bf21dc), I have found my texmf location and created folder where I stored .cls and .sty files of the document template:

```
[user@hostname ~]$ kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
/home/user/texmf
[user@hostname ~]$ 

[user@hostname ~]$ kpsewhich wlscirep.cls
/home/user/texmf/tex/latex/scirep/wlscirep.cls
[user@hostname ~]$
```

After this, the texmaker is still writing that it can not find the wlscirep.cls file. Does somebody see what I miss? I am stucked... :-(

Thanks, Rene

Comment: When I open the document e.g. /home/user/document/main.tex in the texmaker, the texmaker see it as /run/user/1000/doc/e0b0b460/main.tex file. No idea why. The file really exist at HDD. I have tried to copy there all other files which are originally stored in the /home/user/document folder, but it did not help. I still get the same error message. The texlive I have installed as `sudo dnf install texlive*`. The texmaker I have installed via CentOS 8 `Software` app, while I was not able to find any working sudo dnf install command for the CentOS 8 version.

Answer (score 1):

The annoying problem you have run into is a sandboxed app: texmaker is installed as a flatpak, and as such has no access to many places.
Using  flatseal (also installed using the software tool) you can turn on the two file system options (especially the "All user files"); that will solve your problem, I hope.

Comment: So that is still broken; don't have the time to dive into flatpak path settings, but something is not right. TeXworks and TeXstudio work (also only in flatpak). At some point I need to complile a native rpm fortexmaker; this is just annoying.

Comment: `texmaker` is available in the EPEL repository (see https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/install-epel-linux for enabling the EPEL repository), it's maintained by the Fedora team rather than the Red Hat team so not enabled by default but generally worthwhile and reliable.